# How do I build my own IOS/ android chat interface integrated to Watson

Tags: ios, chat, chatbot, watson-conversation, facebook-chatbot

I have developed a Watson conversation, integrated to my own middle-ware using botkit and as front end it already working with Facebook messenger.

I want to replace Facebook messenger with my own chat interface, is there any open source chat environment suitable for that.

I needs to receive different JSON templates same as Facebook messenger and send messages back to my middle-ware web hook address

Thanks for the support

Comment: I am using [MessageKit](https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit)

Answer (score -1):

if you are not afraid of doing the networking and logic stuff yourself, you could easily use one of the many available open source chat UI's:

- https://github.com/little2s/NoChat (a little old)
- https://github.com/MessageKit/MessageKit (I'd recommend this for you, you can easily adjust this to your Watson needs)